# DAX Conundrum (Summing Results of SUMX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to sum the results that are returned from a SUMX but the total is returning 0.

My data table is as below (CustMaster). The logic is to only sum up items that are positive, therefore the total is 700 units versus 650.

[image: Screeshot]

I'm trying to achieve a table that looks like the below, where data is consolidated by customer
[image: Screeshot]

```
=
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( CustMaster[Customer] ),
    MAX ( 0, SUM ( CustMaster[Promised Qty] ) - SUM ( CustMaster[Fulfilled Qty] ) ),
    SUMX (
        CustMaster,
        MAX ( 0,
            ( SUM ( CustMaster[Promised Qty] ) - SUM ( CustMaster[Fulfilled Qty] ) )
        )
    )
)
```

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want those `SUM`s inside `SUMX`.

Try this:

```
SUMX (
    CustMaster,
    MAX ( 0, CustMaster[Promised Qty] - CustMaster[Fulfilled Qty] )
)
```